# Compare two DataFrames for differences but getting 'Can only compare identically-labeled DataFrame objects' error

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to compare two pandas DataFrames for differences using only the columns that are of dtype `bools`.

However using the code below I am getting the error below even though the index is for both df's the same on a `customer_id` level

```
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled DataFrame objects
```

```
BOOL_FIELDS = ['is_mobile','is_desktop','is_cancelled','is_existing_customer']

temp_df = pd.DataFrame()
customer_df_2020.set_index('customer_id',inplace=True)
customer_df_2021.set_index('customer_id',inplace=True)

temp_df['sort'] = (customer_df_2020[BOOL_FIELDS] != customer_df_2021[BOOL_FIELDS])
```

customer_df_2020

```
customer_id   is_mobile  is_desktop  is_cancelled  is_existing_customer
30293          TRUE      FALSE       FALSE         TRUE
28313          FALSE     TRUE        FALSE         TRUE
19313          FALSE     TRUE        FALSE         TRUE
```

customer_df_2021

```
customer_id   is_mobile  is_desktop  is_cancelled  is_existing_customer
30293          FALSE     TRUE        TRUE          FALSE
28313          FALSE     TRUE        FALSE         TRUE
19313          FALSE     TRUE        TRUE          FALSE
```

Comment: It seems in your 2 dataframe that `customer_id` is not set as index.

Comment: customer_id is set as index. Just wasnt sure how to visualise it here

Comment: The shown data does not allow to reproduce. The unequality test betwen both dataframes gives a dataframe of same dimensions (so with 4 columns) that cannot fit into a single column... But the error is not the error you show either. Could you please try to produce a [mre]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems some indices are different, is possible extract same in both by [`Index.intersection`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.intersection.html):

```
BOOL_FIELDS = ['is_mobile','is_desktop','is_cancelled','is_existing_customer']

customer_df_2020.set_index('customer_id',inplace=True)
customer_df_2021.set_index('customer_id',inplace=True)

sameidx = customer_df_2020.index.intersection(customer_df_2021.index)

temp_df  = (customer_df_2020.loc[sameidx, BOOL_FIELDS] != 
            customer_df_2021.loc[sameidx, BOOL_FIELDS])
```

Comment: I am getting the same error:  customer_df_2020.loc[sameidx, BOOL_FIELDS])

Comment: @user12625679 - what is `print (len(sameidx))` ?